# row number based on unique column value in oralce?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I do need to implement a oracle sql to have row number defined as below:

```
row_num, column1, column2, cloumn3
1, ABC, 123, a1
1, ABC, 125, a2
2, ABD, 123, a3
2, ABD, 124, a4
2, ABD, 125, a5
3, ABE, 123, a1
```

Here I defined row number based on unique value of column1.

Can any one help me to write oracle sql to define row number in this way?

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as well, but I forgot about `dense rank`. So Boneist's answer is better.

```
select rn.row_num , t.* from 
(select column1,row_number() over (order by column1) as row_num from 
(select distinct column1 column1 from tbl23) )rn
inner join tbl23 t
on rn.column1=t.column1
```

Comment: @VenkataRamireddyCH out of sheer curiosity, why have you gone for the solution that uses an analytic function (`row_number()`), a distinct and an inner join, rather than the solution which just uses a single analytic function? I don't doubt that Utsav's answer will work for you, but it's unlikely to be the most performant answer...

Comment: I mentioned the same in the answer that yours is better

Comment: @Utsav I can only conclude that my use of the WITH clause to generate test data confused the OP somewhat. Just to be clear, I'm not griping that my answer wasn't picked, I'm just very surprised! I'd be just as surprised if it had been someone else who'd written the same answer I gave! *{:-)

Comment: I understand. Surprised me too :) I hardly upvote any other answer to the same question where I answer. But in this case I did :)

Answer (score 2):

You need the `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'ABC' col1, 123 col2, 'a1' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABC' col1, 125 col2, 'a2' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABD' col1, 123 col2, 'a3' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABD' col1, 124 col2, 'a4' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABD' col1, 125 col2, 'a5' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'ABE' col1, 123 col2, 'a1' col3 FROM dual)
  -- end of subquery mimicking your_table with data in; See SQL below:
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY col1) row_num,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3;

   ROW_NUM COL1       COL2 COL3
---------- ---- ---------- ----
         1 ABC         123 a1
         1 ABC         125 a2
         2 ABD         123 a3
         2 ABD         124 a4
         2 ABD         125 a5
         3 ABE         123 a1
```

`DENSE_RANK()` is similar to `RANK()` in that it will assign tied rows the same rank (that is, rows that have the same values in the columns being ordered - in your case, col1), but unlike `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()` won't skip rank numbers.

Comment: I tried with `row_number` but `dense rank` is perfect approach in this case. +1 :)